# LU Decomposition MPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi

This is a MPI code for LU Decomposition.

I have used the following strategy -

There is a master(rank 0) and others are slaves. The master sends rows to each slave.
Since each slave might receive more than row, I store all the received rows in a 
buffer and then perform LU Decomposition on it. After doing that I send back the 
buffer to the master. The master does not do any computation. It just sends and receives.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    map[i] = i%(numProcs-1) + 1;

for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    if(rank == 0)
    {
        status = pivot(LU,i,n);

        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            row1[j] = LU[n*i+j];
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&status, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(status == -1)
        return -1;

    MPI_Bcast(row1, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int tag1 = 1, tag2 = 2, tag3 = 3, tag4 = 4;

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        int pno, start, index, l, rowsReceived = 0;
        MPI_Request req;
        MPI_Status stat;

        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            MPI_Isend(&LU[n*j], n, MPI_DOUBLE, map[j], map[j], MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);

        if(i>=n-(numProcs-1))
            cnt++;

        for(j=0; j<numProcs-1-cnt; j++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&pno, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            //printf("1. Recv from %d and j : %d and i : %d\n",pno,j,i);
            MPI_Recv(&rowsReceived, 1, MPI_INT, pno, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            MPI_Recv(rowFinal, n*rowsReceived, MPI_DOUBLE, pno, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);

            /* Will not go more than numProcs anyways */
            for(k=i+1; k<n; k++)
            {
                if(map[k] == pno)
                {
                    start = k;
                    break; 
                }
            }

            for(k=0; k<rowsReceived; k++)
            {
                index = start + k*(numProcs-1);

                for(l=0; l<n; l++)
                    LU[n*index+l] = rowFinal[n*k+l];
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        int rowsReceived = 0;
        MPI_Status stat, stats[3];
        MPI_Request reqs[3];

        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            if(map[j] == rank)
                rowsReceived += 1;


        for(j=0; j<rowsReceived; j++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&rowFinal[n*j], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        }

        for(j=0; j<rowsReceived; j++)
        {
            double factor = rowFinal[n*j+i]/row1[i];

            for(k=i+1; k<n; k++)
                rowFinal[n*j+k] -= (row1[k]*factor);

            rowFinal[n*j+i] = factor;
        }

        if(rowsReceived != 0)
        {
            //printf("Data sent from %d iteration : %d\n",rank,i);
            MPI_Isend(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
            MPI_Isend(&rowsReceived, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);
            MPI_Isend(rowFinal, n*rowsReceived, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[2]);
        }
        //MPI_Waitall(3,reqs,stats);
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that sometimes the program hangs. My guess is
that the sends and receives are not being matched but I am not being able to 
figure out where the problem lies.

I ran test cases on matrices of size 1000x1000, 2000x2000, 3000x3000, 5000x5000 
and 7000x7000. **Presently the code hangs for 7000x7000**. Could someone please help
me out?

**Things to note :-**

1. **map** implements the mapping scheme, which row goes to which slave.
2. **rowsReceived** tells each slave the no of rows it will receive. I dont need to 
   calculate that each and every time, but I will fix it later.
3. **row1** is the buffer in which the active row will be stored.
4. **rowFinal** is the buffer of the rows being received and being modified.
5. **cnt** is not important and can be ignored. For that the check for
   rowReceived!=0 needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never completing your nonblocking operations. You have a bunch of calls to `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv` throughout the code, but you're never doing an `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` (or one of the similar calls). Without that completion call, those nonblocking calls will never complete.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I was able to fix it.